# How to use data in this specific format like cartesian? (php)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, algorithm

i have database with table called 'fields'. There are fields of some table. This table has columns: ID field, ID column, ID row, value. How to make double array from this data?

It should be look like this:

```
array {

    array {field1, field2, emptyfield, field3 },
    array {fieldnext, valueoffield, field, emptyfield}
}
```

Each field in database has value, column ID and row ID (like cartesian coordinate system). Important: if any field doesnt exist, function should create this field with value "empty field"

I create some code, but it doesnt fill empty fields with text "empty field". I cant find solution of this problem, I need your help :)

```
 //result is array made from db result
 //rows is output array

 for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++) {

  if(!is_array($rows[$i2])) $rows[$i2]=array();

   if($result[$i]['id_row']==$result[$i-1]['id_row'] OR $i==0) {

     array_push($rows[$i2], $result[$i]['value']);       

   } else {

     $i2++;
     $rows[$i2]=array();

     array_push($rows[$i2], $result[$i]['value']);  
   }
 }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding the line

```
if(empty($result[$i]['value'])) $result[$i]['value'] = 'empty field';
```

at the top of the for loop block.